# Different term for 'fee rate'

Tags: transaction-fees, terminology

Lot of users are confused between fee rate and fee. Sometimes even developers make mistakes or use 'fee' for everything to avoid confusion which can be considered misleading.

Was there ever a different term for 'fee rate' used by any bitcoin project? Is there a term which can be used for it?

Example: If someone wants to talk about the rate at which a distance was covered, 'speed' or 'velocity' is used for it and we don't mention 'distance rate'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Sometimes even developers make mistakes or use 'fee' for everything to avoid confusion which can be considered misleading.

Language is hard, and will at times confuse everyone. That doesn't mean better or newer terms are the solution.

> Was there ever a different term for 'fee rate' used by any bitcoin project? Is there a term which can be used for it?

I don't know of any other commonly used term, though if I had the opportunity to choose a term today, perhaps I would suggest "fee level".

That said, trying to effect a change to this commonly accepted term today would add more confusion than it removes, I think.